# Using a string with boolean operators Swift

Tags: swift

I'm making my first app, a nutrition app that asks the users gender and added sugar.  It gives a grade based on four possible outputs.

Here is an example.  The problem arises when I try to enter "female" for genderField.  It can't use strings with boolean operators.  How do I rewrite so the user can enter female instead of a 1?  Thanks so much!

```
var sugarField = 8.0

var sugarValue = 5.0

var genderField = 1.0


if genderField == 1.0 && sugarField >= 16.6 * calorieRatio { sugarValue = 0.01 }

if genderField == 1.0 && sugarField >= 11.0 * calorieRatio && sugarField < 16.6 { sugarValue = 1 }

if genderField == 1.0 && sugarField > 8.3 * calorieRatio && sugarField < 11 * calorieRatio { sugarValue = 2 }

if genderField == 1.0 && sugarField <= 8.3 { sugarValue = 3 }


print("\(sugarValue)")
```

Comment: Just a recommendation, but in Swift, usually a suffix of `Field` is reserved for text fields (the actual UI control, not the string or double value).

Answer (score 1):

Often, rather than a string, we might define an [enumeration](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html) for situations where you have a fixed set of values, e.g.

```
enum Gender {
    case male
    case female
}
```

(Obviously, add whatever cases you want to your enumeration.)

Then you can do things like:

```
let gender: Gender = .female
```

If you had a `UITextField` for the input, you could translate the `text` to an appropriate gender value:

```
let gender: Gender

switch genderTextField.text?.uppercased() {
case "MALE", "M":
    gender = .male
case "FEMALE", "F":
    gender = .female
default:
    print("Invalid gender")
    return
}
```

Or

```
if gender == .female && sugarField >= 16.6 * calorieRatio { sugarValue = 0.01 }
```

See [The Swift Programming Language: Enumerations](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html).

---

This begs the question as to how you’d capture the user’s selected gender in the user interface. You said you’re using a text field, but if an iOS app, when dealing with lists of finite values, we might use a [segmented control](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/segmented-controls/) or a [picker](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/pickers/).

Comment: Yes, I entered to data in text fields.  If I had known, I may have used a segmented control or picker.  I converted the text fields into Double, so I could enter the formulas.  I tried entering the code you suggested, 'enum Gender {
    case male
    case female}  if genderField == .female && sugarField * calorieRatio <= 8.3 { sugarValue = 3 }', but I got the error Type 'Double' has no member 'female'.  Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: Yeah, but converting it to a double doesn’t make much sense. So make `genderField` a `Gender` property. And you can then do stuff like `if genderTextField.text == "male" { genderField = .male else if genderTextField.text == "female" { genderField = .female} else { ... }` where the `...` is whatever you want it to do if the input wasn’t valid. Or use segmented control or picker instead. (In the time it took you to type that question, you could have just removed the text field and added the segmented control, for example.)

Comment: I can tell you are very knowledgable, but I am still learning things as I go and this is taking too much time, so I am just putting in the placeholder text "enter 1 for female and 2 for male.   I have it working that way already.  Not very eloquent, but I can always change it later.  I just don't want to get bogged down with this.  Thanks for the very insightful advice.  I'll come back to it later.

Comment: I have tried to implement some of your suggestions.  I have inserted a segmented  control and added the suggested enum.  My problem comes in at the last line when I get the error type Bool has no member 'female'.

 switch genderSegment.uppercased() {
 case "MALE", "M":
     gender = .male
 case "FEMALE", "F":
     gender = .female
 default:
     print("Invalid gender")
     return
 }
     
   let sugarFieldConv : Double = Double(sugarField.text!)!
      
      var sugarValue = 10.0
     if gender = .female && sugarFieldConv >= 16.8 * calorieRatio {sugarValue = 1 }